# Can a HIVE SELECT combine GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm doing some relatively simple queries in Hive and cannot seem to combine `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in a single statement. I have no problem doing a select into a temporary table of the `GROUP BY` query and then doing a select on that table with an `ORDER BY`, but I can't combine them together.

For example, I have a table `a` and can execute this query:

```
SELECT place,count(*),sum(weight) from a group by place;
```

And I can execute this query:

```
create temporary table result (place string,count int,sumweight int);
insert overwrite table result 
      select place,count(*),sum(weight) from a group by place;
select * from result order by place;
```

But if I try this query:

```
SELECT place,count(*),sum(weight) from a group by place order by place;
```

I get this error:

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:45 mismatched input '' expecting \' near '_c0' in character string literal (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `group by` as a sub-query and `order by` as an outer query as show below:

```sql
SELECT 
    place, 
    cnt, 
    sum_ 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        place, 
        count(*) as cnt, 
        sum(weight) as sum_ 
    FROM a 
    GROUP BY place
) a 
ORDER BY place;
```

Answer (score 2):

use [sort by](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy) like this:

```
SELECT place,count(*),sum(weight) from a group by place sort by place;
```

Comment: I tried `SORT BY` and got similar results. According to the documentation that you quote, the only difference between `SORT BY` and `ORDER BY` is that `ORDER BY` guarantees total ordering, whereas `SORT BY` sorts the input to the reducer, so there may not be a consistent total ordering. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm only try help :)
...There are some limitations in the "order by" clause. In the strict mode (i.e., hive.mapred.mode=strict),...
...The mode in which the Hive operations are being performed. In strict mode, some risky queries are not allowed to run. For example, full table scans are prevented (see HIVE-10454) and ORDER BY requires a LIMIT clause...

Comment: I appreciate your help! Adding the LIMIT didn't help, alas, but it did help separating into two SELECTs.